# how to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 from my DVD to my Azure virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I'm migrating a Visual Basic windows app from my home Windows 2008 physical server up to my new Azure VM.

I have a purchased Visual Studio 2010 DVD.
Using my Visual Basic 2010, I created a publish package folder and copied it up to the VM.

How do I install my Visual Studio 2010 DVD up to the VM, so that I can run the package on the VM?

Comment: Create an ISO image of the disc and then upload to the VM to install.

Answer (score 0):

What Lex Li commented seems appropriate.

**First**, convert the DVD to an ISO. Here are two links to get you started:

- [Simple utility to rip ISO's on Windows (7)](https://superuser.com/questions/166996/simple-utility-to-rip-isos-on-windows-7)
- [What is the best way to make an ISO file out of a DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/17260/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-an-iso-file-out-of-a-dvd)

**Second**, copy the ISO to the Virtual Machine.

**Third**, mount and run the ISO image on the VM. [How do you extract/install from an .iso file?](https://superuser.com/questions/17309/how-do-you-extract-install-from-an-iso-file) will get you started.